# how to convert html table to bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an HTML table with the help of dynamic data coming to my page, but I want to show the table as bootstrap with a minimum change. I actually want to place this table under div using bootstrap and also want to give bootstrap table class to this HTML code and I don't know how to make this to the bootstrap table.

Here is the code:

```
 var table= $("<table>");
table.append($("<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th><th>col4</th><th>col5</th></tr>"));
var row=$('<tr class="parent_row" >' + '<td>'+ "1" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "2" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "3" + '</td>' + '<td>' +  "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td></tr>');

table.append(row);
//child row
var row=$('<tr style="display: none">' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "4" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "5" + '</td></tr>');
var row1=$('<tr style="display: none">' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "4" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "5" + '</td></tr>');

table.append(row);
table.append(row1);

$("#table").html(table);
$("#table").show();
$('.parent_row').click(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil(".parent_row").toggle();
})
    table  {
       bgcolor = "#FFF" 
       margin-top: 20px;
       margin-left: 10px;
       border-collapse: collapse;
       word-break: break-all;
       overflow-x: auto;
       
       //cellspacing="10"
       width: 5;
       
     }

    th {
       border: 1px solid black;
       text-align: left;
       //width: 20%;
       padding:15px;
       cursor:pointer;
       background-color: #000000;
       color: white;
       
     }
     

    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: left;
      //width: 200px;
    }
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table id="table">

    </table>
```

Comment: you have to add relevant classes from bootstrap into your table. Check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/

Comment: in my code where I should add relevant class to make it bootstrap table as I dont want to change the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
var table= $("#table");
table.append($("<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th><th>col4</th><th>col5</th></tr>"));
var row=$('<tr class="parent_row" >' + '<td>'+ "1" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "2" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "3" + '</td>' + '<td>' +  "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td></tr>');

table.append(row);
//child row
var row=$('<tr style="display: none">'  + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "4" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "5" + '</td></tr>');
var row1=$('<tr style="display: none">' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "4" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "5" + '</td></tr>');

table.append(row);
table.append(row1);

$("#table").show();
$("#table").addClass("table table-bordered");
$('.parent_row').click(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil(".parent_row").toggle();
})
```

Comment: and what should i change in html content, because I am not getting result?

Comment: @Rahul pls check this solution.

Comment: you have added some bootstrap link to make this code work?

Comment: what code you used in your html content? it is same?

Comment: @Rahul You just need bootstrap cdn or file link added in code.

Comment: $("#table").addClass("table table-bordered"); This is code which is need to convert  simple table to bootstrap table.

Comment: You just need to add bootstrap class on your table

Comment: I am getting the same result which i was getting earlier, not the one like table-bordered class?

Comment: @Rahul check the live working code: https://codepen.io/ankurtmishra/pen/PowoMzq

Comment: but this is same view , which I was getting earlier, bordered class of bootstrap table is not like this?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_bordered&stacked=h , see this link how table borderd bootstrap table looks like

Comment: @Rahul in this case you have to remove your css that you write for table, td, th

Comment: Can u show your code on any plateform like codepen, jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

1. Insert boostrap css from cdn
2. add bootstrap class to your html
3. remove your css

```js
var table= $("<table class='table'>");
        table.append($("<thead><tr><th scope='col'>col1</th><th scope='col'>col2</th><th scope='col'>col3</th><th scope='col'>col4</th><th scope='col'>col5</th></tr><thead/>"));
        var row=$('<tbody><tr class="parent_row" >' + '<td>'+ "1" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "2" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "3" + '</td>' + '<td>' +  "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td></tr><tbody/>');

table.append(row);
//child row
var row=$('<tr style="display: none">'  + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "4" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "5" + '</td></tr>');
var row1=$('<tr style="display: none">' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "4" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "5" + '</td></tr>');

table.append(row);
table.append(row1);

$("#table").html(table);
$("#table").show();
$('.parent_row').click(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil(".parent_row").toggle();
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">

    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var table= $("#table");

table.append($("<thead><tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th><th>col4</th><th>col5</th></tr></thead>"));
var row=$('<tbody><tr class="parent_row" >' + '<td>'+ "1" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "2" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "3" + '</td>' + '<td>' +  "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td></tr></tbody>');

table.append(row);
//child row
var row=$('<tr style="display: none">'  + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "4" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "5" + '</td></tr>');
var row1=$('<tr style="display: none">' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "4" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "5" + '</td></tr>');

table.append(row);
table.append(row1);

$("#table").addClass("table table-bordered");

$("#table").show();

$('.parent_row').click(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil(".parent_row").toggle();
})
```

Comment: @Rahul pls check this